# spikes in training CNN using Adam

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, tensorflow, adam

I have an instability issue when training CNN on high dimensional data.
I train Unet-3D model (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf) with batch normalization layer before each convolution layer.

My data dimensions are (46,46,5,77) meaning set of 3D voxels for each feature estimating target of (48,48,5).

I use tensorflow with keras API (tf version 2.3)

I train with default learning rate(LR) of Adam and it happens quite randomly.

I reduce the learning rate after about 600 epochs of no higher change than 1e-4 in validation loss.

Even using quite lower LR it still occurs.
I monitor the metrics using tensorboard callbacks.
my model summary:

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 46, 46, 5, 7 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding3d (ZeroPadding3D)  (None, 48, 48, 5, 77 0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder00 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 187200      zero_padding3d[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder00 ( (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 360         conv_encoder00[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder00 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 0           batch_normalization_encoder00[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder01 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 218790      leakyrelu_encoder00[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder01 ( (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 360         conv_encoder01[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder01 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 0           batch_normalization_encoder01[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pool_encoder00 (MaxPooling3 (None, 24, 24, 5, 90 0           leakyrelu_encoder01[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder10 (Conv3D)         (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 109395      max_pool_encoder00[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder10 ( (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 180         conv_encoder10[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder10 (LeakyReLU) (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 0           batch_normalization_encoder10[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder11 (Conv3D)         (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 54720       leakyrelu_encoder10[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder11 ( (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 180         conv_encoder11[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder11 (LeakyReLU) (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 0           batch_normalization_encoder11[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pool_encoder10 (MaxPooling3 (None, 12, 12, 5, 45 0           leakyrelu_encoder11[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder20 (Conv3D)         (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 18240       max_pool_encoder10[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder20 ( (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 60          conv_encoder20[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder20 (LeakyReLU) (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 0           batch_normalization_encoder20[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_encoder21 (Conv3D)         (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 6090        leakyrelu_encoder20[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_encoder21 ( (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 60          conv_encoder21[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_encoder21 (LeakyReLU) (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 0           batch_normalization_encoder21[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_encoder (Dropout)       (None, 12, 12, 5, 15 0           leakyrelu_encoder21[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv_decoder00 (Conv3DTransp (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 18270       dropout_encoder[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder00 ( (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 180         up_conv_decoder00[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder00 (LeakyReLU) (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 0           batch_normalization_decoder00[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 24, 24, 5, 90 0           leakyrelu_encoder11[0][0]        
                                                                 leakyrelu_decoder00[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder01 (Conv3D)         (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 109395      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder01 ( (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 180         conv_decoder01[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder01 (LeakyReLU) (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 0           batch_normalization_decoder01[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder02 (Conv3D)         (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 54720       leakyrelu_decoder01[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder02 ( (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 180         conv_decoder02[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder02 (LeakyReLU) (None, 24, 24, 5, 45 0           batch_normalization_decoder02[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_conv_decoder10 (Conv3DTransp (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 109440      leakyrelu_decoder02[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder10 ( (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 360         up_conv_decoder10[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder10 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 0           batch_normalization_decoder10[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 48, 48, 5, 18 0           leakyrelu_encoder01[0][0]        
                                                                 leakyrelu_decoder10[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder11 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 437490      concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder11 ( (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 360         conv_decoder11[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder11 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 0           batch_normalization_decoder11[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder12 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 218790      leakyrelu_decoder11[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_decoder12 ( (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 360         conv_decoder12[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder12 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 90 0           batch_normalization_decoder12[0][
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder20 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 45 109395      leakyrelu_decoder12[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder21 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 1) 1216        conv_decoder20[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_decoder22 (Conv3D)         (None, 48, 48, 5, 1) 28          conv_decoder21[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leakyrelu_decoder20 (LeakyReLU) (None, 48, 48, 5, 1) 0           conv_decoder22[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,655,999
Trainable params: 1,654,589
Non-trainable params: 1,410
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

example of loss
[image: training loss over epochs]

second example of loss
[image: training loss over epochs]
third example of loss

[image]

Comment: What's your batch size here? It seems difficult to train for 2K epochs on image data, unless your dataset is very small...

Comment: Does this also happen if you turn off dropout? My hypothesis is that these transient spikes occur when a large number of units are dropped in an iteration due to the randomness of dropout.

Comment: @tchainzzz my data set is 4320 elements and I use batch size of 240 since I have memory limitations. It's not image data but more like synthetic data with high dimensions but of type float32.

Comment: @Sycorax It's a good question I'll give it a try. I somewhere read that it helps in better robustness of the model